# How can I get a missing value from "where in ()" in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table with a column named "Ids" and another column named "clients" and I have the following data:

```
IDs     Clients
----------------
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
```

I'm trying to get the IDs for multiple clients without writing a query for each one.

So I am using:

```
select ids 
from table1 
where clients in (A,B,E,C)
```

This returns

```
1,2,3
```

But I need to know that E is missing. So I really need

```
1,2,NULL,3
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How do you know which clients it will be? Where does A,B,E,C come from?

Comment: I don't know which clients it will be, hence the query. I need get ids for a list of clients that I have whether they are in the data base or not. If not, then I need to know they are not a client.

Comment: I know it's a duplicate. I've even answered a question like this myself, probably more than once. Can't find it, though... Oh, well, Paparatzzo have a good answer there, note his comment about the plural column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inline the values

```
declare @t table (id int, client char(1))
insert into @t values 
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C'),
(4, 'D');

select * 
from @t;

SELECT q.client, t.id
FROM ( values ('A'), ('B'), ('E') ) q(client)
left join @t t
on t.client = q.client;
```

Don't use plural for columns.  A row is singular.

Comment: Thanks. That works and seems to be the most concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Insert your input to a table and proceed your query as below

```
declare @tbl table (ids int, clients varchar(10))
insert into @tbl values
(1,'A')
,(2,'B')
,(3,'C')
,(4,'D')

SELECT * FROM @tbl

declare @value table (Val varchar(10))

insert into @value values
('A')
,('B')
,('C')
,('E')

select ids,t1.Val
from @tbl t
RIGHT JOIN @value t1 on t1.Val = t.clients
```

Alertnate option.

```
declare @tbl table (ids int, clients varchar(10))
insert into @tbl values
(1,'A')
,(2,'B')
,(3,'C')
,(4,'D')
```

For SQL Server 2016 and above

```
Declare @var varchar(50) = 'A,B,C,E'
SELECT ids, t1.value
FROM @tbl t
RIGHT JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@var, ',') t1 on t1.value = t.clients
```

For lower than SQL Server 2016 use below query.  You have to create strparse function. script given below

```
SELECT ids, t1.Keys
FROM @tbl t
RIGHT JOIN dbo.StrParse (',', @var) t1 on t1.Keys = t.clients

go
```

Create the function for parsing string to rows

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StrParse]
               (@delimiter CHAR(1),  
                @csv       NTEXT)  
RETURNS @tbl TABLE(Keys  NVARCHAR(255))  
AS  

  BEGIN  
    DECLARE  @len INT  
    SET @len = Datalength(@csv)  
    IF NOT @len > 0  
      RETURN  

    DECLARE  @l INT  
    DECLARE  @m INT  

    SET @l = 0  
    SET @m = 0  

    DECLARE  @s VARCHAR(255)  
    DECLARE  @slen INT  

    WHILE @l <= @len  
      BEGIN  

        SET @l = @m + 1--current position  
        SET @m = Charindex(@delimiter,Substring(@csv,@l + 1,255))

        IF @m <> 0  
          SET @m = @m + @l  
        --insert @tbl(keys) values(@m)  
        SELECT @slen = CASE   
                         WHEN @m = 0 THEN 255
                         ELSE @m - @l  
                       END 

        IF @slen > 0  
          BEGIN  
            SET @s = Substring(@csv,@l,@slen)  
            INSERT INTO @tbl  
                       (Keys)  
            SELECT @s  
          END  

        SELECT @l = CASE   
                      WHEN @m = 0 THEN @len + 1
                      ELSE @m + 1  
                    END
      END  

    RETURN  
  END
```

Comment: That's a lot of machinations just to get a select query result.

Comment: @user2721815 That's only a lot of operations if you're thinking about it backwards. A where clause is not sufficient because by definition it will filter out any records that don't match its filter. The issue is the data in your filter has meaning outside of the filtering itself which is exactly what joins are for: set building based on more than one set. However, you can't join on non-tabular data. One potential optimization to this answer is to create a function that returns a table structure with the comma separated values you provide which you can then use to join like you see above.

Comment: Which SQL Server version you are using?  If you are using SQL Server 2016 or above then you can use String_Split function as @S.C. said

Comment: I'm sorry to be the one to have to tell you this, but your `StrParse` function is terrible. If you want to split strings prior to version 2016, go read Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). Even the worst function in his article is better then the RBAR atrocity you posted.